# Disabling button functionality for a particular tableview cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, invalidation

I have the following process. Each tableview cell has an objectId referenced as a label. When a user presses the like or dislike button in that cell, the objectId in that cell is saved to a PFUser's currentUserObjectIdsTouched("array"). When  a particular user  has already liked or disliked the cell based off of their currentUserObjectIdsTouched, I want to disable both like and dislike functionality for that particular cell. I have got everything up until disabling. How do I disable both buttons.

My button syntax in cellForRow is... cell.likesButton()

```
     cellForRow:

        if currentUserObjectIdsTouched.contains(cell.objectId.text!) {
            print("should invalidate buttons for cell with objectId \(cell.objectId.text!)")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this inside `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.likesButton.isEnabled = !(currentUserObjectIdsTouched.contains(cell.objectId.text!))
```

It's good practice to compare from the model directly like

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
let item = arr[indexPath.row]
cell.likesButton.isEnabled = !(currentUserObjectIdsTouched.contains(item.objectId))
```

Comment: error returns:     value of type '(Any) -> ()' has no member 'isEnabled'

Comment: My button is not connected to my current VC. It is nested inside a nib cell.

Comment: create an iboutlet for it and do what in answer

Comment: The nib file doesn't allow a connection to the VC, only a connection to its swiftFile: Tableview cell.

Comment: yes connect it to the cell class and then cast the dequeued cell to yours see edit

Comment: This works thanks. Unfortunately though I believe since the tableview is deque cell. The recycled cell invalidates all cells that are set for that tableview. How do I disable this?

Comment: That's not how it works.  A new cell instance is created for each visible row in `cellForRowAt`.  If there are cells that have scrolled out of view, they are reused (the tableview maintains a list of cells that are no longer displayed) as it has a lower overhead than creating new ones.   If no cells are available for reuse the tableView will create new instances as required.  If a row scrolls off screen and then back on it (usually) doesn't reuse it's previous instance of a cell, but is assigned a new one in `cellForRowAt`.  This is why recycling a cell doesn't invalidate the visible cells.

Comment: Ok for some reason cells that have object Ids that aren't part of the array also become disabled upon viewdidload.